# how to select boolean fields in django model

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 models in different apps:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    vsej_seti = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('Все сети'))
```

and

```
class Hotel(ServioResource):
    stock_all = models.ForeignKey('content.Stock', related_name='st', null=True, blank=True)
```

Please help me to write a method which sort all booleanfields with true parametr. In sql it looks like "`SELECT * FROM content_stock WHERE vsej_seti=1`". I wrote smth like this, but it doesn't work. Thanks

```
    def qqq(self):
        f = False
        if self.stock_all.vsej_seti == f:
            return self.stock_all.vsej_seti
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a queryset filter

```
def qqq(self):
    return self.stock_all.filter(vsej_seti=True)
```

Note: There may be more efficient queries avaiable depending on your use case but this is easily modified as per [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/)